# Why does my React-Native app slow down when it is moved to background

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have an app that is issuing lots of fetch API requests.  On Android, it runs great in foreground.  In background, it continues to run but it seems to slow down dramatically.  I am running on a Samsung Note 20 Ultra.  My app is a react-native app... javascript.  Does anybody know what could be causing this?

The app issues lots of fetch requests.  About 1 a second.  At first, all seemed to work well.  Then I added a fetch that returned lots of data.  I have a loop that processes that data.  That processing loop runs fine in foreground but slows to about 1/5 the speed in background.  The code will not issue another until the last was processed so I know I am not stacking up work.  I tried slowing down the other fetch requests while the loop is running but that does not seem to help.  And, it seems to work fine when the app is in the foreground.    I already know react is single threaded but this alone should not change its behavior in foreground vs. background.  I made sure the app does not issue any screen writes while in background.  If I remove the processing of the large data fetch, it does not seem to slow down in background.  It works the same in foreground and in background.  Maybe the hard loop processing has exceeded some sort of samsung threshold for CPU usage by a background app?  Does anybody know if samsung restrict processor availability while an app is in background?  Is there a way to prevent this?

The code being executed in the foreground task is as follows:

```
  const collectCurrentStockPrices = async (realTimeStockPriceData) => {
    console.log('Got Here');
    percentageDone = 0;
    var myCurrentTimestamp = Date.now();
    myCurrentTimestamp = myCurrentTimestamp/1000;

    for (
      realTimeStockPriceCounter = 0;
      realTimeStockPriceCounter < realTimeStockPriceData.tickers.length - 1;
      realTimeStockPriceCounter++
    ) {

      globalRealTimeStockPriceCounter = realTimeStockPriceCounter;
      realTimeStockPriceQueryArrayIndex = indexOfTicker(
        realTimeStockPriceData.tickers[realTimeStockPriceCounter].ticker,
        trackedStocks,
      );
      if (realTimeStockPriceQueryArrayIndex !== -1 && realTimeStockPriceData.tickers[realTimeStockPriceCounter].day.c !== 0 ) {
        if (Math.floor(realTimeStockPriceCounter/100) === realTimeStockPriceCounter/100) {
          percentageDone = (globalRealTimeStockPriceCounter / realTimeStockPriceData.tickers.length) * 100; 
          ReactNativeForegroundService.update({
            id: 1244,
            title: "AI Stock App",
            message: "Collecting Current Prices",
            icon: "ic_launcher",
            button: false,
            button2: false,
            buttonText: "",
            button2Text: "",
            buttonOnPress: "",
            setOnlyAlertOnce: true,
            color: "#000000",
            progress: {
              max: 100,
              curr: percentageDone,
            },
          });
        }
        if (globalDebugOn) {
          if (Math.floor(realTimeStockPriceCounter/100) === realTimeStockPriceCounter/100) {
            console.log('Processing Current Price: ' + realTimeStockPriceCounter + " " + realTimeStockPriceData.tickers[realTimeStockPriceCounter].ticker + " Value: " + realTimeStockPriceData.tickers[realTimeStockPriceCounter].day.c );
            if (AppState.currentState === 'active') {
              setDetailedStatusText('Processing Price: ' + realTimeStockPriceCounter);
            }
          }
        }
        // Use muCurrentTimestamp set above.... you want the timestamp at the 
        //    time of the query and not at the time the record was updated
        // myCurrentTimestamp = Date.now();
        // myCurrentTimestamp = (myCurrentTimestamp / 1000).toFixed(0);
        realTimeStockPriceDateToStore =
          '{ "CurrentPrice" : ' +
          realTimeStockPriceData.tickers[realTimeStockPriceCounter].day.c +
          ', "CurrentPriceTS" : ' +
          myCurrentTimestamp.toString() +
          ' }';
        try {
          realTimeJSONStockPriceData = JSON.parse(realTimeStockPriceDateToStore);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
          console.log(
            'JSON Parse 42 failed on: ' + realTimeStockPriceDateToStore,
          );
        }
        realTimeStringStockPriceData = JSON.stringify(realTimeJSONStockPriceData);
        try {
          await AsyncStorage.mergeItem(
            realTimeStockPriceData.tickers[realTimeStockPriceCounter].ticker,
            realTimeStringStockPriceData,
          );
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
        // Get the value back to see if it was stored correctly
        //  .... instead, lets just put it directly in storage (speeds things up)
        try {
          jsonTrackedStocksRecord = JSON.parse(trackedStocks[realTimeStockPriceQueryArrayIndex][1]);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
          console.log(
            'JSON Parse 43 failed on: ' + trackedStocks[realTimeStockPriceQueryArrayIndex][1],
          );
        }
        jsonTrackedStocksRecord.CurrentPrice = realTimeStockPriceData.tickers[realTimeStockPriceCounter].day.c;
        jsonTrackedStocksRecord.CurrentPriceTS = myCurrentTimestamp;
        trackedStocks[realTimeStockPriceQueryArrayIndex][1] = JSON.stringify(jsonTrackedStocksRecord);
        // try {
        //   realTimeStockPriceTestValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem(
        //     realTimeStockPriceData.tickers[realTimeStockPriceCounter].ticker,
        //   );
        // } catch (error) {
        //   console.log(error);
        // }
        // if (realTimeStockPriceCounter === 0 || realTimeStockPriceCounter === 1) {
        //   console.log(
        //     'Newly Written Stock Price Data: ' + realTimeStockPriceTestValue,
        //   );
        // }
        // Now update the tracked stocks in memory to reflect the changes
        //trackedStocks[realTimeStockPriceQueryArrayIndex][1] = realTimeStockPriceTestValue;
      } else {
        // if ticker in stock price record is not good
        // console.log(
        //  'Found bad ticker in stock price query: ' +
        //    stockPriceData.results[stockPriceCounter].T,
        //);
        // Delay a couple hundred milliseconds to allow other code to execute while
        //   this is in a hard loop
        await delay(200);
      }
    } // loop through stock price results for (realTimeStockPriceCounter)
    processingRealTimeStockPrices = false;
    ReactNativeForegroundService.stop({
      id: 1244,
      title: "AI Stock App",
      message: "Collecting Current Prices",
      icon: "ic_launcher"
    });
  }
```

Comment: Pretty much all devices on Android and even IOS run background tasks slower, this is normal.   To even get background tasks running often requires more work, and this makes total sense, can you image how long your phones battery would last if all App's on your phone that ran in the background consumed resources.  You will likely find after a certain period you background app will even pause totally, unlses you configure a service like -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-task

Comment: Thanks. I use react-native-background-timer.  It works pretty well.  I have run the app for weeks at a time with no issue.   One thing I did not mention is that it works with no slowdown on an android studio emulator.  Perhaps that is because of the quicker pc processor.  The other surprising thing is that slowing down the number of queries I issue in the background while running this processing loop does not seem to help.... perhaps the tight processing loop (which processes apprx 11K items) eats more resources than the literally thousands of queries that I forego.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please add some c ode that what you are doing in background-timer.

Comment: The code being executed in the foreground service is now above.... it is javascript... I am using react-native... there was a fetch done previously that creates a data structure that is passed to this routine which then loops through it to process it.

Comment: `setDetailedStatusText` is state update you are doing?

Comment: Yes, it is changing a status that is displayed on the screen.  This is why I only set it if the app is in the foreground.